# Fetching Issues on Google Webmaster tool

Tags: google-search-console

Trouble in Fetching on Google webmaster Tool a and Can't fetch the website link on Google webmaster tool.. Got any solution for this ??? Problem in Fetching

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message that comes up?

Can you do a screenshot?

If Google cannot fetch the page successfully - it is more likely to a problem with your server than a problem with Google (assuming you have tested a few times - Google does have the occasional error once in a blue moon).